# How to inject instance with [Dependency] attribute using Unity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am using Unity for dependency injection in ASP.NET C#.

Normally I would inject dependencies in the constructor, like:

```
class MyClass
{
   private readonly ISomething _something;

   public MyClass(ISomething something)
   {
      _something = something;
   }

   public MyMethod()
   {
      // _something is instantiated as expected
   }
}
```

where the dependency has been configured as:

```
container.RegisterType<ISomething, Something>();
```

That's all great.

But now I need to do an injection without the use a constructor. So I read that I can use the dependency attribute [Dependency] for this purpose.

```
class MyClass
{
   [Dependency]
   private ISomething _something { get; set; }

   public MyMethod()
   {
      // _something appears to be null
   }
}
```

But for some reason _something appears to be null.

What am I missing?

**SOLUTION:**

See the accepted answer over here, which shows how to create a factory to generate the injected instance:

[How to resolve dependency in static class with Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30388081/how-to-resolve-dependency-in-static-class-with-unity)

Worked for me!

Comment: "But now I need to do an injection without the use a constructor." Why do you need this?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to inject into a private property. This is not possible.

And personally, I suggest you stick to constructor injections to prevent locking yourself into a specific Dependency Injection framework.

Comment: I updated the question with a solution. So it is indeed possible to do - and it worked well for me.